# Last char on the line is being "left out" in many situations

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor-motions

For example, wanting to delete the last 3 words from the current line, I press `$d3b` but I still have the last char from that line not deleted. Is that normal? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [Matt's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21962/18609), `b` is an exclusive motion. Using visual mode is a possible way to work around this.

Alternatively, you can also use `v` as an operator (instead of entering visual mode), like so: `$dv3b`

See [`:help o_v`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#o_v), which explains it:

> `v`: When used after an operator, before the motion command: Force the operator to work characterwise, also when the motion is linewise.  If the motion was linewise, it will become exclusive. **If the motion already was characterwise, toggle inclusive/exclusive.**  This can be used to **make an exclusive motion inclusive** and an inclusive motion exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

`b` is an `:h exclusive` motion, so it behaves this way: "*the last character towards the end of the buffer is not included*". Make sure you choose appropriate tools.

Note that it's true for the normal mode. In the visual mode everything depends on `:h 'selection'` option value. So, if `set selection=inclusive` (default) then `$v3bd` does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Matt's answer addresses the why, but requires the extra keypress of visual mode to solve your problem. (And [there are suggestions that visual mode is less "vim-like"](https://whileimautomaton.net/2008/11/vimm3/operator), at least when alternatives are available.)

For deleting the last 3 words, one sequence might be `$3bD`, no longer than your original, where you position first and delete last.

A (much longer) regex oriented solution:

```
:s/\v(\w+\W*){3}$//
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers addressed why this happens. One way around this that I prefer is just to use forward motions instead of backwards motions. Because `w` is an inclusive motion and `b` is an exclusive motion, in general you can do

```
bdw
```

instead of

```
db
```

In this particular case since you want to delete from the end of the line, you could use `D` to delete to the end of line which is a bit shorter:

```
$3bD
```

or a more general solution would be

```
3bd3w
```

Comment: `w` is exclusive. `$3bd3w` works because it's as special case : `last word moved over is at the end of a line` . It's documented after `:h WORD`